# How to wrap text for a data field tag in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am passing a value for the text tab (data field tag) through the docusign restapi. If the value is long enough, then it's passing over the document page  but i want it to break it into another line or wrap up into few lines. I am using properties of custom tags to specify the maximum length and number of lines which is not working as expected.Is there any line breaker or text wrapper in docusign?

Comment: I don't think it's a stupid question, but \r\n formatting does work in DocuSign value's :)

Comment: Oops!! Sorry, I deleted my previous comment. Yeah, I tried \r\n and it's working for that signer only. When the document goes to next signer, this value is again populating as Single line only....

Comment: Well, actually the tab value could possibly have 60-100+ 8 digit numbers that is passed from SF to docusign. So the signer for whom, this tab has been assigned to,  '\r\n' is working as line breaker  and showing the values properly but when the signing process completed and later looking at the complete document with all the signatures and this tab shows only first row, all the other values are gone. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your REST call, so I can see exactly what params you're passing? (just throw test data in there please). It sounds like you just need to set the datafield line height / width, but it's hard to tell without really seeing the call.

Comment: Thanks for the response...you are right!! I missed the height and width parameters; I found out from the docusign community.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Comment: Hi Sam, any way you could post your solution as an answer for the benefit of the community?  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to declare height and width parameters in the docusign api call when creating a custom data field/text tab. For reference, use this link

https://community.docusign.com/t5/Sending-Options-and-Features/Text-Wrap/td-p/6017

Here is the sample JSON format to declare a new text tab in api call which displays 90 characters wide per line and up to 10 lines.

> "textTabs": [{ "name": "Text", "value": "123", "required": True,
>   "locked": false, "concealValueOnDocument": false, "disableAutoSize":
>   false, "tabLabel": "tablabel", "documentId": "1", "recipientId": "1",
>   "pageNumber":"1", "height":"110", "width":"540", "xPosition": "1",
>   "yPosition": "1" }]

Note: Not all the above values are required when creating a new tab. Please check [Docusign REST API guide](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm)  for reference.